# Manual dynamic enhancement with openjpa on intellij

Tags: java, openjpa

I am trying to use openjpa and mysql to persist a single class, nothing dramatic really.

```
Attempt to cast instance "xxx" to PersistenceCapable failed.  Ensure that it has been enhanced.
```

So I looked around and found this
https://openjpa.apache.org/builds/2.2.1/apache-openjpa/docs/ref_guide_pc_enhance.html
where they suggest the use of

```
java -javaagent:/home/dev/openjpa/lib/openjpa.jar com.xyz.Main
```

Now I added this to my VM-Options in my intellij runtime configurations:

```
-javaagent:/home/xxx/Downloads/apache-openjpa-3.1.2/openjpa-all-3.1.2.jar main.java.entity.Post
```

But it does not seem to recognise the class:

```
You have enabled runtime enhancement, but have not specified the set of persistent classes.  OpenJPA must look for metadata for every loaded class, which might increase class load times significantly.
```

I thought the 2nd argument for javaagent is me specifiying the class but I am wrong.

This is my persistence.xml:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.2"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd">
<!-- Define persistence unit -->
<persistence-unit name="post">
    <class>main.java.entity.Post</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="openjpa.DynamicEnhancementAgent" value="true"/>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DSTEST" />
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="xxx" />
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="xxx" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

And this is my entity:

```
package main.java.entity;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity (name="post")
public class Post {
@Id
private Integer postid;

private String user;

private Integer datum;

private String inhalt;

public Integer getPostid() {
    return postid;
}

public void setPostid(Integer postid) {
    this.postid = postid;
}

public String getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(String user) {
    this.user = user;
}

public Integer getDatum() {
    return datum;
}

public void setDatum(Integer datum) {
    this.datum = datum;
}

public String getInhalt() {
    return inhalt;
}

public void setInhalt(String inhalt) {
    this.inhalt = inhalt;
}
}
```

I am using Intellij on Ubuntu.